# Dashing in Unity 2D using the Rigidbody Component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, rigid-bodies

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float movementSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D Rigidbody;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    public Transform Player;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ProcessInputs();
    } void FixedUpdate()
    {
        move();
    }
    void ProcessInputs()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;
    }
     void move()
    {
        Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * movementSpeed, moveDirection.y * movementSpeed);
    }

}
```

---

So i needed some tips so i thoght id ask here, i wanted to implement dashing in my Top-Down-Shooter but i didnt find any code on Youtube that would properly work with my code i have also tried moveing the players position +2 to the wanted direction but i couldnt work it out.
id be happy if yall could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Nice that you are using FixedUpdate() for physics - many beginners use that wrong.
However do not set velocity manually. Use AddForce.
It will effectively set the velocity but automatically takes the objects mass into account and allows to speed up instead of instantly being at speed.
That is the more logical approach since you move in a direction by applying forces to your body.

For Dashing, you could add a significantly higher force for a small number of Physics frames (aka small number of FixedUpdate calls). You can use a countdown which you set to a number when the chaarcter hsould start dashing.
In the FixedUpdate you decrement the counter and as long as it is >0 you apply the dashing force.

Comment: Oh alright thanks that makes sense, but how do i code it so it only goes for like a second and not as long as i press it, should i use input.getkeydown(Keycode.Space) or should i do something else ?

Comment: Yes, that function in update() to set the counter to a target value. You could also use https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html